# How to create multiple pages in windows forms without creating multiple forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program were creating at school in c# and I need to create multiple pages which display information on certain things but I'm not quite sure how to do this without creating over 50 new forms in my program. I know parameters have to be used but I'm not quite sure how to go about doing it.

Comment: Please refer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you give us some examples about the data these forms will handle and what they will do?

Comment: What you mean by "page" in Winfoms?

Comment: Form is just another c# class, having 50 forms is not a problem. Better to have 50 forms where every form doing own thing, will be much easier to maintain than one form with logic of 50 forms.

Comment: Perhaps you might be able to use a Tab control.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use TabControl

You can add pages and name them how you want.
Controls, you are adding to a tab, are still active, even if you move to another tab.